# Why is remote desktop so laggy?

Tags: remote-desktop

I am remoting to my desktop through my network and when I connect my cpu usage jumps up from 20 percent to 70 percent and it's really laggy. What could be causing this? Is it not using my GPU?

```
Desktop OS:  Ubuntu 22.04 lts
Remote desktop server:  Apache Guacamole
Remote system OS: unspecified
```

Comment: Could be.  Some additional information may help:  What OS is your remote desktop on, what os are you using to connect to the remote desktop?  What connection method are you using to make the connection?

Comment: @CharlesGreen ubuntu desktop 22.04 LTS and I'm using apache guacamole. VNC connection.

Comment: Interesting.  It would have been a bit more appropriate to update the question, I will do that as an example.  Guacamole uses web browsers to perform the remote desktop, and has been mentioned in some performance related issues on reddit and sourceforge back in 2019 and 2020 (google apache guacamole performance).  You might check to see if your browser is using the GPU.  Other than that, I am a little limited in what help I can offer, perhaps someone else might know more than I